# How do I run postgres on heroku for my discord.py bot?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, connection, discord.py

So I am using heroku (for now) to host my discord.py bot.
Recently I started using postgres as a database, this is the connection code:

I am using this code for connection:

```
import asyncpg

async def create_db_pool():
    client.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(DATABASE_URL) #db url goes here

client.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

The code works absolutely fine when I run it locally, but shows connection error while I use heroku for the same.

I also added 'Heroku-postgres' as an add-on but it still doesn't work?
Please share a solution for the same.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using the heroku database or are you hosting it somewhere? If yes, where?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I don't want to save the data in the heroku database, I am using the default server of postgres i.e. pgAdmin4 to save data.

Comment: that explains you everything, you're running the server on localhost, no one can connect to it apart from yourself. You need to either use the heroku database or host the databasse e.g on aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(DATABASE_URL) #db url goes here
```

When you add a Postgres DB addon Heroku will add an environment variable to your app. The value of it containing a database url. You need to retrieve that. Something like:

```
import os
DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("ENV_VAR_NAME_HERE", None)
```

---

> @ŁukaszKwieciński I don't want to save the data in the heroku database, I am using the default server of postgres i.e. pgAdmin4 to save data.

Your Heroku app does not come with a database. Anything that is saved on the Heroku app is wiped, see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). There is no "default server of postgres" on your Heroku app. That's why you are adding a (third party) add-on to your app that acts as the database: the postgres add-on.